# Set up & Verify Godaddy domain (MX, CNAME, TXT, SRV) in Google Cloud DNS

Tags: networking, email, dns, google-cloud-platform, godaddy

I have a domain with Godaddy as my Registrar.
Set up an email with them as I'm hosting my site with Google Cloud.
*Reason: Google Cloud has restrictions on sending mail from VM Instances.*

Pointed the domain via NS to Google Cloud DNS and have to update/add records there as they are now the primary DNS provider.

*GoDaddy needs me to verify my domain ownership* (yes WTF right??)
and request that I enter MX, CNAME, SRV & TXT with Google Cloud DNS.

**This is the info they gave me to enter (domain name replaced with example.com)**

---

> > Let's get your mail going to the right place
> > Before we can finish setting up your account, we need to verify that you own example.com.

Log in to your account with your current DNS host.

**Set the following TXT records.**

```
Name    TXT Value
@       D1029331
@       v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all
```

**CNAME Records:**

```
Host    Points to
email   email.secureserver.net
```

**MX Records:**

```
Host    Priority    Target
@          0        smtp.secureserver.net
@          10       mailstore1.secureserver.net
```

**SRV Records:**

```
Port    Protocol  Name   Service           Priority   Weight    Target
443     _tcp      @      _autodiscover     100        1         autodiscover.secureserver.net
```

---

**Problem**
I have followed instructions and entered records, after more than 72hrs - not resolving.

**Question:**
Please assist if you can and let me know if I entered the records correctly.
(Current Record Settings Screenshot) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xnva.png

**PLEASE NOTE:**
I have asked Godaddy Support - They are not very useful and point me to Google Support.
*Google offers no support* unless you are on a paid support tier - which is expensive.

Thanks,

HendrikE

Comment: Your question is hard to follow. You registered a domain with GoDaddy. You pointed its NS records at GCP. So far, so good. Then you set up an e-mail account with GoDaddy(?). And now you’re having trouble setting up the required DNS for this e-mail service, correct? Have you tried actually querying all the records you set up from your home connection?

Comment: Your screenshot shows **example.com**. My guess is that you have incorrectly set up the SOA and NS resource records. Your question does not include that information. Use Internet tool to check your resource records: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx

Comment: @Daniel B - Yes. I set up a Wordpress site on Google Cloud. The DNS works. I can access the website. The problem is I cannot send mails from the VM Instance as Google blocks the smtp and ports. Hence you have to set up your own mail. Which I did, at GoDaddy. Now GoDaddy needs me to add the records in order to verify I own the domain. Which is confusing as thry are my Registrar and should know this. The information above is what they give. So I entered it on my Cloud DNS console. But, not resolving the MX, TXT, Cname or SRV.

Comment: @John Hanley - The domain points and works. I can access the website and with DNSChecker.org the normal DNS records do resolve and work 100% The problem is verifying the MX, TXT, Cname and SRV info which I received from GoDaddy and need to enter in GCloud DNS. Ive done that (as per example screenshot) and it does not resolve.

Comment: 1) create the required resource records at Cloud DNS. 2) Use mxtoolbox to verify that you created the records with the correct values. Edit your question and show the output from mxtoolbox in your question.

Comment: Check my answer below - not sure if the site bots will allow such a short answer through.

Answer (score 0):

After trying every option I have reverted back to using Godaddy as my DNS provider which solved the problem.

Should someone be able to do this set up - please reply and leave your steps here for someone else in the future.

Tx

Answer (score 0):

Having followed [this](https://community.godaddy.com/s/question/0D53t00006Vm2uXCAR/email-from-godaddy-to-google-cloud-platform), simply put... remove the `@` in front of your DNS entries.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).